# How to add arraylist into Map

Tags: android, dictionary

im trying to mimic this structure to post data to mailchimp, im using volley

```
{
 "email_address": "testchimp@gmail.com",
    "status": "subscribed",
    "merge_fields": {
        "FNAME": "testmailchimp",
        "LNAME": "testingit",
     }  
}
```

i have done this, but i need to add the FNAME and LNAME and i dont know how to  do it right

```
 @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("email_address","testchimp@gmail.com");
                params.put("status","unsubscribed");
                //here i want to add the arraylist FNAME and LNAME
                return params;
            }
```

> Solved my problem with this

```
final JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject("{\"email_address\":\"mailchimptester@gmail.com\"," +
                "\"status\":\"unsubscribed\"," +
                "\"merge_fields\":{\"FNAME\":\"test\",\"LNAME\":\"teste\"}}");
```

So with this i can do the json how i want without maps and then validate it here https://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an `ArrayList` it would be a `Map`. You can do it using this code

```
HashMap<String,String> merge_fields = new HashMap<>();
merge_fields.put("FNAME","testmailchimp");
merge_fields.put("LNAME","testingit");
String merge_fields_param = new JSONObject(merge_fields).toString();
params.put("merge_fields",merge_fields_param);
```

Comment: I logged the output but somehow I'm messing the previous steps. This is what I'm getting:

{status=subscribed, merge_fields={"FNAME":"testmailchimp","LNAME":"testingit"}, email_address=mail@ottaaproject.com}

And I need the same structure as in the post

Comment: I think what you need is a Json object but the volley params aren't giving you that. Instead they are individual params

Comment: if i use postman with raw and i imput what i ask in the question, the first json  text , it posts to me correctly , but im trying to mimic that structure inside my app to send it to the mailchimp, but i cant do it

Comment: I think you need to use `JsonObjectRequest`. Look at this [link](http://envyandroid.com/android-volley-empty-parameters/) and provide these params through the `JsonRequest` object

Comment: final JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject("{\"email_address\":\"mailchimptester@gmail.com\"," +
                "\"status\":\"unsubscribed\"," +
                "\"merge_fields\":{\"FNAME\":\"test\",\"LNAME\":\"testero\"}}");